# dynamically load post data depending on route - angular 4

Tags: angular, loops, routes, ngfor

I'm working on Angular 4 Blog, I added the pagination and loop through the posts.

now what I need is how to loop a specified post depending on route, like this :

if the url `http://example.com/posts/tools/1` the page will load the data of post has the id = 1

the question is how to do that ? I tried using another ngFor to loop but it loop through the all posts not loop through the single post .

for full code : [Github](http://github.com/pro-devel/angular4-blog)

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router, so you can use route parameters https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service

Comment: @Moema I already toked a look at routes parameters but if you take a look of my github repo you will find that I'm using a json as a data so the format looks like this [
{
"id": "1",
"title":"someTitle",
"otherStuff":"others"
},
{
"id": "1",
"title":"someTitle",
"otherStuff":"others"
}
]

Comment: @Moema so how can I use something like this id.title that will show the title of that id ?

Comment: My mistake , i figured out how to use it like a javascript loop thanks